# Why is the datalayer showing in sourcecode but not in GTM debugger

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

The following datalayer push appears to be deployed correctly after an action is clicked on a website.
I can see that this code is loading onto the page after the click fires, this full datalayer push script is then visible within the source code.
But when using the GTM debugger, there is no sign of the event, or the datalyer information.
Is this an issue with the data layer code, or perhaps how or when it is fired?

```js
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
'event': 'addressResult',
'postcode': '3415',
'availability': 'limited'
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you support your question with some screenshots and more detail of your problem? There is no problem with the code you provided and there is nothing to go on in your question.

Comment: Ok so I worked out the answer, the dataLayer push requires the original GTM code to correctly define the 'dataLayer' but instead, the default deployment shortened this to dl there for the dataLayer was referring to a variable that wasn't technically established.